# Bounds on some integral involving the Sawtooth function

Tags: analytic-number-theory

This is from the book **A Course in Analytic Number Theory** from Marius Overholt involving the sawtooth function:
$$S(x)=x-\lfloor x \rfloor-{1\over{2}}$$
Proposition 1.6.(page 11)
*If $1 \leq a\leq b$ the estimate*

$$\left | \int_a^b{S(x)\over{x^s}}dx\right|\leq \left(  {1\over{8}}      +{\left|s\right|\over{16\sigma}}              
              \right)a^{-\sigma}$$ 
*holds for any complex number $s=\sigma+it$ with positive real part* $\sigma$

Proof (taken from the book):
**If**
$$\beta(x)={1\over{16}}+\int_0^xS(u)du$$
then $\left|\beta(x)\right|\leq{1\over{16}}$. Integration by parts gives:

$$\left|\int_a^b{S(x)\over{x^s}}dx\right|=\left| {\beta(x)\over{x^s}}\Bigl|_a^b-\int_a^b(-s){\beta(x)\over{x^{s+1}}}dx \right|  \leq2.{1/16\over{a^{\sigma}}} +\int_a^b\left|s\right|{1/16\over {x^{\sigma+1}}}={1\over{8a^{\sigma}}}-{\left|s\right|\over{16\sigma}}{1\over{x^{\sigma}}}\Bigl|_a^b \leq {1\over{8a^{\sigma}}}+{\left|s\right|\over{16\sigma}}{1\over{a^{\sigma}}}$$
The integration by parts part seems baffling to me. Could someone smart explain the equality: $$\left|\int_a^b{S(x)\over{x^s}}dx\right|=\left| {\beta(x)\over{x^s}}\Bigl|_a^b-\int_a^b(-s){\beta(x)\over{x^{s+1}}}dx \right|  $$

Comment: Observe that $\beta'(x)=S(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Could someone smart explain the equality:* $$\left|\int_a^b{S(x)\over{x^s}}dx\right|=\left| {\beta(x)\over{x^s}}\Bigl|_a^b-\int_a^b(-s){\beta(x)\over{x^{s+1}}}dx \right|  $$

One may recall that, integrating by parts,
$$
\int_a^b u(x)\cdot v'(x)\:dx =\left[ u(x)\frac{}{} v(x)\right]_a^b-\int_a^b u'(x)\cdot v(x)\:dx
$$ then applying it with
$$
u(x):=\frac1{x^s},\qquad u'(x)=-\frac{s}{x^{s+1}},
$$$$
v'(x):=S(x)=\beta'(x),\qquad v(x)=\beta(x)={1\over{16}}+\int_0^xS(u)du
$$ one gets
$$
\int_a^b \frac{S(x)}{x^s}\:dx =\left[ \frac1{x^s}\cdot \beta(x)\right]_a^b-\int_a^b(-s){\beta(x)\over{x^{s+1}}}\:dx
$$ giving the desired equality with absolute values.

Comment: May I additionally ask, what is the role of the constant  1/16 than, it could be any other constant.